# Use Microphone and Headphones on a splitter

Tags: windows-7, audio, microphone, headphones, splitter

I bought this thing:
http://www.dhgate.com/store/product/3-5mm-1-male-to-2-female-earphone-headphone/157719473.html
From a shop.My laptop have only a jack port and i don't have Headphones with microphone.And i need this thing to connect my microphone and my headphones on it.I don't know if this works.I tryed this and i can't find the microphone on any program.The headphones are working.

Windows 7 Premium Home |x86| Quad Core

Comment: If you need a Microphone use a USB one, because you won't be able to use the one you have, if it requires a 3.5mm ( or whatever ) plug

Comment: Can i use a Jack - USB adaptor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That adapter is a splitter, it doesn't turn a jack into a headphone and microphone. Headphone jacks send signals out, to the headphones, while microphone jacks accept incoming signals, from the microphone. There are combination jacks, which your computer might have, but you'd need to either look up the details on your specific laptop, or give them to us here so we can check that.

If your laptop does not have a dedicated microphone jack, you should be able to purchase a USB microphone to use instead.

UPDATE:

From the product website (http://us.acer.com/ac/en/US/content/model/NX.MGRAA.002) we learn your device has a built-in microphone, probably right near the built-in webcam.

There is not information specifying which sort of headphone jack it is. However, there will likely be icons next to the headphone jack indicating whether it supports just headphones, or if it's a combo jack that supports microphones as well.

If it is a combo connector, you should be able to purchase a combination headphone/microphone such as are sometimes used for cell phones. If it is not a combo unit, and you do not want to use the built-in microphone, you'll need to purchase a USB microphone as I suggested earlier.

Comment: It's a Acer Aspire E1-510.
I bought it 2 mounths ago.
I will search the details.

Comment: It's a combo jack :D

Comment: So i need a Jack with L R Gnd and MIC... Yep, now i understand.

Comment: Glad to have helped. Go ahead and mark my answer as the correct one (the checkmark under the vote up/down buttons).

Comment: Ok ,i marked it;) I want to vote up the answare but i don't have 15 reputation

Comment: You'll get there. Believe it or not, I once had 1 point too.